# How to change a button's text, based on input on text field

Tags: flutter

I have a small popup with a button "DELETE", however I want to change the text to "SELL" everytime the input text is different than 0.00

```
showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          String _popUpDeleteSoldText = "Delete";
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text("Delete " + doc['propertyName'] + "?"),
            content: Container(
              height: 120,
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextField(
                    onChanged: (text) {
                      if (text != "0.00") {
                        print("i'm != 0.00");
                        setState(() {
                          //TODO - THIS AIN'T WORKING
                          _popUpDeleteSoldText = "Sell";
                        });
                      } else {
                        print("i'm still 0");
                        setState(() {
                          _popUpDeleteSoldText = "Delete";
                        });
                      }
                    },
```

the button:

```
MaterialButton(
                elevation: 4.0,
                child: Text(
                  _popUpDeleteSoldText,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                )
....
```

The print are working on the onChange function, but the button text always say "Delete"

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to extract your AlertDialog into a separate `StatefulWidget` and then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap with StatefulBuilder directly like the following example
String contentText will change after use setState

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    String contentText = "Content of Dialog";
    return StatefulBuilder(
      builder: (context, setState) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Title of Dialog"),
          content: Text(contentText),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
              child: Text("Cancel"),
            ),
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  contentText = "Changed Content of Dialog";
                });
              },
              child: Text("Change"),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```